# Best way to concisely store frequently used methods

Tags: java

I have worked on quite a few projects in the past where I've used the same types of methods in several different classes. Here's a quick example:

```
public class ClassA {

    ...

    public int methodA(){

    }

    ...

}

public class ClassB {

    ...

    public int methodA(){
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

I may have several classes that want to use this method, and they may not necessarily follow the same structure, so an interface shouldn't be used.

What would be the best way to store this method in Java so that I don't have to write it out in every single class and waste precious lines? I have thought about having a class to store these helper methods, but I may have quite a few methods that are shared between classes, so I'm just trying to find the nicest way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "same types of methods"? Is the code identical, and you are just copy-pasting?

Comment: 90% of the time the methods will be identical, yeah. I assume if there is any alteration to the method it must be rewritten for the class it pertains to

Comment: There is no "best way" that covers all cases. It depends on what kinds of alterations happen in that 10%, because it's likely even then that you don't have to rewrite the entire method.

Comment: @4castle Yes, in the 10% case we can probably extract out a common method, and reuse that.  It depends on the situation though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a helper class and then declare `methodA()` as a static utility method:

```
public class MethodHelper {
    public static int methodA() {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

You can this consume this method as follows:

```
public class ClassA {
    ...

    public void doSomething() {
        int value = MethodHelper.methodA();
    }
}
```